# Keeping my search bar viewable when my navbar collapses with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a nabvar that contains a search field 'navbarSearchQuery'. When the navbar collapses when the screen shrinks to a phone size I want 'navbarSearchQuery' to remain visible in the navbar. Is there something I can do with @media queries to keep it visible or do I have to move it outside the collapsable section in the navbar?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">Yoga</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Groups</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Neighborhoods</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes, you have move it out of that div `collapse navbar-collapse` to not have the search collapse as well.

Comment: Here's one way you can do it. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/rdc7Leef/

Comment: it seems like this might have some css tweaking for alignment issues. What about putting it in the navbar-header div? I'll post something as an answer and see if there is any more tweaking to get things look better.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form inside the `navbar-header`.

```css
/**Custom**/

.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-custom .formSearch {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-left: 160px;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-custom .inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: black;
}
.navbar-custom .left-addon .glyphicon {
  left: 0px;
}
.navbar-custom .left-addon input {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .formSearch {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    background: #f5f5f5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button><a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">Yoga</a>

      <form class="formSearch" role="search">
        <div class="inner-addon left-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Friends</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Groups</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Neighborhoods</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can put the navbar in the header part but when I shrink the alignment is slightly off. Can this be fixed?

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/Home">Yoga</a>
  <div class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="navbarSearchQuery" name="location">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

before and after pics. you can see the button isn't aligned correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this work for what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/nefvrf6j/

Comment: yes but I want the searchbar to stretch across the top when its small taking up any extra white space